# How do I stop the C# compiler output from wrapping in the Visual Studio 2015 output window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, word-wrap

When I build my C# code in Visual Studio 2015 using the default compiler (nothing unusual about the project), I get output in the output window that looks a bit like this. (The actual width isn't representative, as I've replaced the rather long path with `XXX`.)

`1>XXX(402,13,402,16): error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'Lo
1>g' cannot be used like a method.
1>XXX(424,25,424,28): error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'Lo
1>g' cannot be used like a method.`

Presumably the compiler is printing `Non-invocable member 'Log' cannot be used like a method`, and something, somewhere, is stepping in and popping newlines in (at column 120 in practice - as mentioned, column counts in my example output are unrepresentative).

Can I stop this? If so, how?

I'd much prefer the messages to be printed out with newlines in natural places, so I can use the output window's word wrap functionality.

Comment: The message itself is printed out with no newlines at all. Run MSBuild at command prompt and you get the truth. The unnatural wrapping comes from VS Output panel itself, which you have no way to fix, and I wonder why do you even care about that? What do you do with the Output panel?

Comment: Hmm, no, it doesn't wrap.  Sometimes I wish it did.  That it is prefixed with 1> indicates that it is not wrapped by Visual Studio.  Odd compiler you are using, don't make us guess please.

Comment: I'm still able to reproduce this in VS2019.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you open the Package Manager Console, build output starts to become wrapped as above.

The fix appears to be to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: This is only temporary, you'll have to restart VS every time.

Comment: I've found the fix to be permanent, but after this experience I never ran the Package Manager Console again.