# Visual Studio – Output window – text width

Tags: window, output, width

When I launch a build in Visual Studio 2015 and observe the build output in the Output window in Visual Studio, I see that the length of almost all lines in the Output window is limited to 79 characters, although the window is much wider. It looks like this:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
(1820,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the sa
me dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property t
o true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/f
wlink/?LinkId=294190.`

Consequently, the output is too long vertically. How can I remove this limitation or at least increase the line length limit?

Comment: Possible answer (worked for me): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456668/how-do-i-stop-the-c-sharp-compiler-output-from-wrapping-in-the-visual-studio-201